# Grails query map where object1 hasMany object2

Tags: grails, hql, grails-orm

I want to do a query like this:

I have a `Tale` that `hasMany` `secondaryTags`

and the query I am trying to do is the following:

```
def query = 'select new map(title as title,
                            mainTag as mainTag, 
                            secondaryTags as secondaryTags) from Tale order by rand()';
def result = Tale.executeQuery(query, [max: 3])
```

But as `secondaryTags` is a `Collection` of `Tag` it doesn't work. Does anyone know how I do this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A join is required to fetch the associations. Try this query, it should work:

```
select new map( tale.title as title,
                tale.mainTag as mainTag, 
                sts as secondaryTags ) 
       from Tale as tale
       inner join fetch tale.secondaryTags as sts
       order by rand()
```

since you are seeking a `map`. Otherwise

```
select tale from Tale as tale
       inner join fetch tale.secondaryTags
       order by rand()
```

should be sufficient to get whatever you need from one query. Also note that `inner join fetch` is used, which means the above query will `eagerly` fetch the association `secondaryTags` from tale in the same query, instead of firing another query to get the association if `tale.secondaryTags` is issued. To witness the fact, enable logging (`logSql = true`) in `DataSource.groovy` and check the behavior of the aforementioned principle.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The first option (the one with the map) doesn't work. It says **query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list**. If I put only `join` without the `fetch`, it returns only one element of the collection. Your second option worked fine, but I wanted to use maps because I need the key-value relationship, and also because it only returns the id of the secondaryTags (without name, etc).